# How to hide visible duplicate cells using AdvancedFilter or any other possible methods?

Tags: excel, vba, visible, advanced-filter

I need to hide **visible** duplicate cells in a range.
With using AdvancedFilter, yes it hides the duplicate cells (entire row) But It also show all the hidden rows in the respective range. 
I tried to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method, But I got the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Database or table range is not valid.

If it is not applicable to use AdvancedFilter, What are the other possible methods? 
As always, gratfull for all your help.

```
Sub Hide_Visible_Duplicate_Cells()
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arng As Range, LastR As Long
 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 
    LastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
    Set arng = ws.Range("A1:A" & LastR)
 
    arng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=arng, Unique:=True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "visible duplicate cells"? Is there a **filtered range**, or you have hidden some rows and need to keep **only one row between all of rows containing the same value in cells of column A:A**?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,yes I already have some hidden rows and I don't want it to be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. It uses a dictionary to detect which rows to be hidden (only after the dictionary key has been created) and set a `Union` range for the respective cells. Finally, `EntireRow` of this range will be hidden:

```
Sub Hide_Visible_Duplicate_Cells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arng As Range, LastR As Long
    Dim C As Range, UnRng As Range, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    On Error Resume Next 'just for the (improbable) case when no cell exist in the respective range
     Set arng = ws.Range("A1:A" & LastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If arng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
   For Each C In arng.cells
        If Not dict.Exists(C.Value) Then
            dict.Add C.Value, vbNullString 'keep the first occurrence
        Else
            addToRange UnRng, C            'create a Union range for the next occurrences
        End If
   Next C
   'hide the rows at once:
   If Not UnRng Is Nothing Then UnRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range) 'Add to the Union range...
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

**Edited**:

The next suggested solution can be called from another `Sub`:

```
Sub Hide_Visible_Dup_Cells(procRng As Range)
    Dim arng As Range, C As Range, UnRng As Range, dict As Object
 
    On Error Resume Next
     Set arng = procRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If arng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'no need of reference...
   For Each C In arng.cells
        If Not dict.Exists(C.Value) Then
            dict.Add C.Value, vbNullString
        Else
            addToRange UnRng, C
        End If
   Next C
   
   If Not UnRng Is Nothing Then UnRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

For the above case, it can be called as:

```
Sub tesHide_Visible_Dup_Cells()
      Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, LastR As Long
      
      Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      LastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
      Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & LastR)
      
      Hide_Visible_Dup_Cells rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. Please, is it possible to make your code as a **function** as I will use it many times on my actual workbook

Comment: @Waleed No need to be a function... It can stay as a `Sub`, only creating `arng as Range` as its parameter. I will adapt it in this way, but not immediately...

Comment: All perfect, Just a note `Sub addToRange` is not added to the edited answer

Comment: @Waleed Since it has been posted above and it is called by the parametrizat `Sub`, I thought it is not necessary to paste it again. It is an edited answer, not a new one... I should also mention (for the first version) that it needs a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`... But, if somebody try using both versions and **tries understanding them** it will be easy to discover that. And you better keep in your mind the issues discovered by yourself...

Comment: Ok, I learned and I will keep any coming notes in my mind, you are correct

Comment: @Waleed No, no, you do not have to keep anything you think should be told, in your mind. Say it! I will only express my opinion. I am not a god, being all the time right... You may take my idea as a good one or  not. I mean, I did not forget about that `Sub`, even if it could happen and it happened in some other cases. I simple considered that in the answer context it is not necessary, anymore.